# How to convert complicated JSON nested data to CSV in Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, export-to-csv

I'm looking to convert a JSON dataset that looks like this:

```
{
  "123456": {
    "question_data": {
      "question_title": "How do I fill out an REU application?",
      "question_body": "It is not a secret that REUs want to encourage higher participation of minority groups, and indeed the web pages of some programs say things like, \"Members of underrepresented groups are especially encouraged to apply.\" ",
      "question_link": "question_1_link",
      "question_user_id": 12485,
      "question_user_aboutme": "Graduate student."
    },
    "answer_data": {
      "answer_number_1": {
        "answer_user_id": "User ID Deleted",
        "answer_user_aboutme": "No user",
        "was_answer_accepted": true,
        "answer_body": " The personal consequences for you of being labeled on your application as a white male are not something that anyone can predict with any certainty."
      },
      "answer_number_2": {
        "answer_user_id": 98456,
        "answer_user_aboutme": " I'm a web developer",
        "was_answer_accepted": false,
        "answer_body": "I would be inclined to not mention race and gender on my applications to REUs in mathematics."
      },
      "answer_number_3": {
        "answer_user_id": 255648,
        "answer_user_aboutme": "Associate Professor.",
        "was_answer_accepted": false,
        "answer_body": "There is just no difference whatsoever between marking white and not saying anything at all."
      }
    },
    "tag_data": [
      "application",
      "united-states",
      "research-undergraduate",
      "gender",
      "ethnicity"
    ]
  },
  "192715": {
    "question_data": {
      "question_title": "What would my appropriate career path be?",
      "question_body": "I'm not sure because I don't have a degree yet. Things I do in the lab would be do experiments (I'm in charge of a control cell line), help her collect data from the experiments and analyse them.",
      "question_link": "question_2_link",
      "question_user_id": 654958,
      "question_user_aboutme": "No user information"
    },
    "answer_data": {
      "answer_number_1": {
        "answer_user_id": 798412,
        "answer_user_aboutme": "Long time CS Professor.",
        "was_answer_accepted": false,
        "answer_body": Learning might be enough, but being exploited isn't a good thing. You should almost certainly expect to be acknowledged by name in any resulting publications."
      }
    },
    "tag_data": [
      "undergraduate",
      "research-undergraduate",
      "science"
    ]
  }
```

into a CSV file that looks like this [CSV Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/at4F4.png)?

I've tried to use JSON normalize through pandas and iterate through to duplicate the rows and put the nested data into the corresponding columns. I'm relatively new to data cleaning in Python and would really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

***Might be a long answer but I wanted to share anyway :)***

***and try these codes on jupyter lab because you understand there well***

## chapter 1

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json

js = """{
  "123456": {
    "question_data": {
      "question_title": "How do I fill out an REU application?",
      "question_body": "It is not a secret that REUs want to encourage higher participation of minority groups, and indeed the web pages of some programs say things like, Members of underrepresented groups are especially encouraged to apply ",
      "question_link": "question_1_link",
      "question_user_id": 12485,
      "question_user_aboutme": "Graduate student."
    },
    "answer_data": {
      "answer_number_1": {
        "answer_user_id": "User ID Deleted",
        "answer_user_aboutme": "No user",
        "was_answer_accepted": "true",
        "answer_body": " The personal consequences for you of being labeled on your application as a white male are not something that anyone can predict with any certainty."
      },
      "answer_number_2": {
        "answer_user_id": 98456,
        "answer_user_aboutme": " I'm a web developer",
        "was_answer_accepted": "false",
        "answer_body": "I would be inclined to not mention race and gender on my applications to REUs in mathematics."
      },
      "answer_number_3": {
        "answer_user_id": 255648,
        "answer_user_aboutme": "Associate Professor.",
        "was_answer_accepted": "false",
        "answer_body": "There is just no difference whatsoever between marking white and not saying anything at all."
      }
    },
    "tag_data": [
      "application",
      "united-states",
      "research-undergraduate",
      "gender",
      "ethnicity"
    ]
  },
  "192715": {
    "question_data": {
      "question_title": "What would my appropriate career path be?",
      "question_body": "I'm not sure because I don't have a degree yet. Things I do in the lab would be do experiments (I'm in charge of a control cell line), help her collect data from the experiments and analyse them.",
      "question_link": "question_2_link",
      "question_user_id": 654958,
      "question_user_aboutme": "No user information"
    },
    "answer_data": {
      "answer_number_1": {
        "answer_user_id": 798412,
        "answer_user_aboutme": "Long time CS Professor.",
        "was_answer_accepted": "false",
        "answer_body": "Learning might be enough, but being exploited isn't a good thing. You should almost certainly expect to be acknowledged by name in any resulting publications."
      }
    },
    "tag_data": [
      "undergraduate",
      "research-undergraduate",
      "science"
    ]
  }
}"""


renames = {
    "index":"Question ID",
    "question_title":"Question Title",
    "question_body":"Question Body",
    "question_link":"Question Link",
    "question_user_id":"Question User ID",
    "question_user_aboutme":"Question User About ME",
    "answer_user_id":"Answer User ID",
    "answer_user_aboutme":"Answer User About ME",
    "was_answer_accepted":"Was Answer Accepted",
    "answer_body":"Answer Body",
    "tag_data":"Tag Data"
    }
```

## chapter 2 - json normalize

```
df = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(js))
cols = df.columns
df
```

## chapter 3 - reindex with multiindex

```
def map_func(x):
    index = x[:x.index(".")]
    column = x[x.rindex(".")+1:]    
    return (index, column)

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(map(map_func, cols))
df = df.unstack().reset_index().drop("level_2", axis=1)
df
```

## chapter 4 - enumerate questions and answers

```
df["que_no"] = df["level_1"].apply(lambda x: 1 if x=="question_user_id" else np.nan).cumsum()

con_df = pd.DataFrame()
groups = df.groupby("level_0")

for g,d in groups:
    d["que_no"] = d["que_no"].ffill().bfill()
    d["ans_no"] = d["level_1"].apply(lambda x: 1 if x=="answer_user_id" else np.nan).cumsum().ffill().bfill()

    con_df = pd.concat([con_df, d], sort=False)
con_df
```

## chapter 5 - groupby question_id and concatenate groups with ordered columns

```
c_groups = con_df.groupby(["level_0","que_no","ans_no"])
result_df = pd.DataFrame()

for g,d in c_groups:
    d["level_1"] = pd.Categorical(d["level_1"], categories=renames.keys(), ordered=True)
    ud = d.set_index(["level_0","level_1","que_no","ans_no"]).unstack("level_1")

    result_df = pd.concat([result_df, ud], sort=False)
result_df
```

## chapter 6 - finish

```
# fill values
result_df = result_df.ffill().bfill()

# fix multiindex for index and columns to singleindex
result_df.index = map(lambda x: x[0], result_df.index)
result_df.columns = map(lambda x: x[1], result_df.columns)

# result
result = result_df.reset_index().rename(columns=renames)
result
```